# Insights and Solutions for a better API construction in Java 11 Springboot framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I've been building java api's in the following way.

> Application.java
> -Controller
> Handler.java
> -Model
> Item.java
> -Service
> Repository.java

```
Application.java

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @CrossOrigin()
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}



Handler

@RestController()
@RequestMapping("item")

public class Handler {
    
    
    @Autowired
    RepositoryProduct rep;
    @CrossOrigin()
    @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Item>> getAll(){
        
        List<Item> p = rep.findAll();
        
        
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Item>>(p,HttpStatus.OK);     
    }
    
}



@RestController()
@RequestMapping("product")

public class HandlerProduct {
    
    
    @Autowired
    RepositoryProduct repProduct;
    @CrossOrigin()
    @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProduct(){
        
        List<Product> p = repProduct.findAll();
        
        
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Product>>(p,HttpStatus.OK);      
    }
    
    
    

}

Repository

public interface RepositoryProduct extends MongoRepository<Item,String>{
    
    

}
```

What can I do to make a better and more secure API?

Any sugestions for better ways to do any of this stuff feel free to say!!! I want to learn :)

See project at https://bitbucket.org/thezerodev/zerohorizon/src/master/

Comment: This will be most likely closed as too broad or opinion-based. Try to reword the question to a more specific one.

Comment: Or post it at Code Review

Comment: Whats that "Code Review"?

Comment: It would need a lot more context to be on topic at [codereview.se].  In its current form, it would be pretty promptly closed there as example/pseudo code.